# make a div in a new created window

Tags: javascript, object

I made a timer that shows up a my new created window.

but, it repeats the text everytime because i write a new line.

i want to make a div element in my window so i can replace (update) the text every second.

object:

```
venster = window.open('new.html','titel','width=500, height= 500');
```

my timer:

```
function stopwatch(sec){
    //timer 
    venster.document.write("window closes in: " + sec);
    if(sec < 1){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        venster.document.write("<h1>i will close!</h1>");
        //setTimeout(venster.close(),2000);
        }
    sec--;
    var timer = setTimeout('stopwatch('+sec+')',1000);
    }
```

i want the text *"window closes in .."* only shown once and not every second a new line of this text.

Comment: `<h1i will close!</h1>` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing an `else` clause. And if you want to replace the entire content then `innerHTML` is what you're after. `document.write` will always just add.

```
function stopwatch(sec){
    if(sec < 1){
        venster.document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>i will close!</h1>"; // Also this h1 wasn't closed
        setTimeout(venster.close ,1000); // And this was executed immediately rather than passing on a function
    } else {
        venster.document.body.innerHTML = "window closes in: " + sec;
        setTimeout(function() { stopwatch(sec-1) }, 1000); // And this would look prettier wrapped in an anonymous function
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm still getting the same text over and over again till my timer is on 0

Comment: Ah hang on I read it wrong. I thought the issue was with the `h1` not the `window closes in` text. `document.write` will always add, not replace

Comment: Then `innerHTML` is what you want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the variable `timer` just exists in the function scope. when you want to clear the timer it has no value.

define the variable `timer` outside of the function.